# Rails won't let me change records during migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

This must be something simple but it's driving me nuts!
I have a migration where I want to update a record afterward

```
class SubjectsTextField < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :subjects, :text

    User.find(39).update_attribute :subjects, "hey there"
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :subjects
  end
end
```

The column gets created but when I go to check record 39, it's subjects field is null and doesn't say "hey there".  No errors are thrown during the migration and the update_attribute line returns true as if it had worked.

This line works perfectly in the console and has the expected effect:

```
User.find(39).update_attribute :subjects, "hey there"
```

I tried putting the update_attribute line in a second migration.  If I blow through both of them in one "rake db:migrate" all the way to current, it still doesn't work.

But here is the weird part.  If I run two separate migrations, say "rake db:migrate VERSION=10" to only create the column and then the second one with "rake db:migrate" to update the attribute IT WORKS!

What the heck is going on...how do I modify a record during a migration?  I seem to remember doing this quite often in the past.  Maybe it is something different with Rails 2.3.2?

Thanks!
Brian

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to call `reset_column_information` on the model you changed before you can use the new column. Add this between the `add_column` and update:

```
User.reset_column_information
```

See "Using a model after changing its table" on the [ActiveRecord::Migration](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) page.

Comment: that was it thanks Michael!  Can't believe I never ran into this before...thanks a million.

Comment: I had a similar issue. Someone didn't use t.timestamps on a migration that created a model, but they did t.datetime :updated_at.  So I wanted to add :created_at and initialize any existing objects' created_at to the current value of updated_at, but it was always nil.  The weird thing was that it worked fine when I tried using Time.now.

Anyway, thanks Michael.  Your post helped a lot!  That fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the link to the api page: it helps to keep updated because on other pages I've found that #reset_column_information method is deprecated..

Comment: This help me out as well. Thx. Just wondering why. My migration actually worked when I first created them then I decided to wipe my db, restore from backup and rerun migrations and it didn't work. Still scratching head as to why it worked the first time but not now. But anyway this got me going.

Comment: Brother, you should get more than +1 -> +100 right now. This has been driving me nuts for hours.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is much clear...try with change_table

```
class AddReceiveNewsletterToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration 
   def self.up 
    change_table :users do |t| 
      add_column :users, :subjects, :text
    end
    User.find(39).update_attribute "subjects", "hey there"
  end  

  def self.down 
   remove_column :users, :receive_newsletter  
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you combine the two in your initial migration like this, does that work?

```
class SubjectsTextField < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :subjects, :text

    User.find(39).update_attribute "subjects", "hey there"
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :subjects
  end
end
```

Comment: Nope doesn't work this way with the quotes, thanks for the response!